# Setting Python path while developing library module

Tags: python

I am developing a library and an application that uses the library in Python 2.6.  I've placed a "mylib.pth" file in "site-packages" so that I can `import mylib` from within my application.

I am using a DVCS so when I want to fix a bug or add a feature to the library I make a branch of the repository and work within that branch.  To test my application with the changes I am making to the library I edit the path in "mylib.pth" to point to the new development branch.

This gets a little tedious if I have a few parallel branches of my library going on at one.  I have to keep editing the "mylib.pth" file before testing to ensure I am testing against the correct version of my library.  Is there a way to use the current path (i.e. the development branch of the library that I am current in) to set the library path when I invoke my application instead of using the "mylib.pth" in the global "site-packages" directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) what you're looking for?  From the description:

> Imagine you have an application that
>   needs version 1 of LibFoo, but another
>   application requires version 2. How
>   can you use both these applications?
>   If you install everything into
>   /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages (or
>   whatever your platform's standard
>   location is), it's easy to end up in a
>   situation where you unintentionally
>   upgrade an application that shouldn't
>   be upgraded.

Comment: It seems like this addresses my problem pretty well.  I ran 'virtualenv .' in the development branch of my library which created 'Lib' and 'Scripts' sub-directories.  I added a modified ".pth" file in './Lib/site-packages' directory.  Then to invoke my application using the development version of my library I run './Scripts/python myApp.py'

Answer (score 4):

Suggested reading: [Tools of the Modern Python Hacker: Virtualenv, Fabric and Pip](http://clemesha.org/blog/2009/jul/05/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/). It addresses a number of problems with development and deployment of Python apps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use setuptools, then you can say `setup.py develop` in your working tree, and it will do the .pth file manipulation for you.

Comment: I'm not currently using setuptools but this looks like a pretty simple solution as well.  I will look into using setuptools.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can alter `sys.path` to add the current directory (or a subdirectory of it) to the search path. `site.addsitedir` is a good way to do it. Since you'd be doing this from Python you can have any sort of logic you like for deciding which directory to add; you could base it on `os.path.normpath`​ing the current directory if it looks like a branch, or looking for the newest branch on-disc, or something else.

You could put this code in the `sitecustomize.py` module or other startup-triggered location.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider using [zc.buildout](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/).  It allows you to create entry points with customized python paths.

Answer (score 1):

I set my `PYTHONPATH` to point to the latest-and-greatest version.  No editing.

```
export PYTHONPATH=.:/the/new/version
```